# Rails 3.2.1 models in modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I have many models in my applications and some of them are closely related to each other so I decided to group them up and make modules.
Here is what I did as an example: http://pastebin.com/qqELTd2k

Now I am curious about three things.

Firstly: do I realy need to specify the module name in relationships, if they do not go outside the module (e.g. the 'belongs_to :status' association in the paste) or it should work withought it properly (I do have a model called Status in the root model directory and it is different from Qna::Status).

Secondly: will that :char association work properly, going outside the Qna module?

Third: Is it a good idea at all to group models like that? It makes the models directory much cleaner, but I am not sure about the common conventions.

**UPDATE**

4th: can I put the qna.rb file discribing the module in the qna folder in app/models?  And if yes, what modifications do I need to do (obviously it does not go that easy).

Comment: Several of those questions can be answered by just trying it.

Comment: It works right now, but I did not find any corresponding information on the docs, so I am not quite sure if it would work later when the app grows bigger. If you need an example of such behavior try rendering an instance variable in a 1st-level partial of the view and in the third. First will work great, but the third would not.

Comment: You shouldn't be using instance variables in partials, but that's an entirely different matter.

Comment: The thing is that not everything that works is something you should realy use.

Comment: Only one of your four questions is about what you *should* do, the other three are about whether or not you can.

Comment: Ok then, if you think they are dummy questions, I can escept that, but how about answering that forth, which in your opinion is on the topic.